# Start external program in it's directory

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, shellexecute

I need to start the external program `c:\pro\prog1.exe` from my project. The external program has its configuration file in the same directory `c:\pro\prog1.ini`. I do:

```
ShellExecute(NULL,L"open",L"c:\pro\prog1.exe" ,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Program `c:\pro\prog1.exe` starts, but it does not load its configuration file `c:\pro\prog1.ini`. It looks like I need to place the `.ini` file in the same directory where my host application is run from. This is not acceptable. So, how to start an external program and ask Windows to run it from its directory?

Comment: Why don't you use the Process class and its ProcessStartInfo support class?. With that you could specify exactly the WorkingDirectory

Comment: you need use `CreateProcess` function - here exist parameter - `LPCTSTR   lpCurrentDirectory` - this what you exactly need

Comment: The 5th parameter is the startup directory: `ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"c:\\pro\\prog1.exe", NULL, L"c:\\pro\\", SW_SHOWDEFAULT);`

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani I'm ready to accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: Alternatively, if *prog1.exe* is under your control, you could consider fixing it instead. Don't make it read it's configuration file from a current-working-directory relative path. Instead, use a fully qualified path by querying for the executable image's pathname.

Answer (score 2):

The 5th parameter in [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) is the startup directory.

Alternatively `"prog.exe"` can use `GetModuleFileName` and `PathRemoveFileSpec` to find its own directory, as suggested in comments.

Note that some directories like `"c:\\Program Files"` and `"c:\\Program Files (x86)"` require elevated access to create/modify/delete files (for example during installation). A process without elevated access, can access files in protected directories with read-only flag. Otherwise Windows will redirect the path to a different directory if write-access is requested.

For normal execution, the *.exe should use `"Documents"` or `"AppData"` folder to read/write data.